# Push alert from alert manager to Grafana

Tags: grafana, grafana-alerts, grafana-api

I want to ask if there is a way how to push alerts from prometheus alert manager into the grafana which runs in a different network. I need to send alert via an API and show it in the Grafana. Does Grafana support such feature? All ports except http and https are blocked so I need to use an API if it is possible. I can easily catch alerts in a script and send via API, I just do not know if grafana has such API.